# Why Multiple y axes subplots in Plotly R are being hidden?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have done a multiple subplot. Here is my code:

```
m <- list(
  #l = 50,
 # r = 50,
  b = 200,
  #t = 100,
  pad = 0
)

    ma <- list(
      #l = 100,
      b = 100,
     # t = 200,
      pad = 0
    )
        p5<-plot_ly(moving_avg,x=~Time,y=~Moving_Average3,type="scatter" ,mode="lines",name ="Memory")%>%
  add_trace(x=~Time,y = ~Moving_Average_Cpu3,mode="lines",yaxis = "y2",name ="CPU")%>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))%>%
  layout(                        
    title = "CPU VS MEMORY(MOVING AVERAGE)",
    xaxis = list(       
      title = "",
      zeroline=TRUE),     
    yaxis = list(        
      title = "MEMORY(%)",
      zeroline=TRUE),
    yaxis2 = list(        
      title = "CPU(%)",
      zeroline=TRUE)

  )%>%
  layout(margin=m)

p6<-plot_ly(moving_avg,x=~Time,y=~Moving_Average3,type="scatter" ,mode="lines",name ="Memory")%>%
  add_trace(x=~Time,y = ~Moving_Average_Cpu3,mode="lines",yaxis = "y2",name ="CPU")%>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))%>%
  layout(                        
    title = "CPU VS MEMORY(MOVING AVERAGE)",
    xaxis = list(       
      title = "",
      zeroline=TRUE),     
    yaxis = list(        
      title = "MEMORY(%)",
      zeroline=TRUE),
    yaxis2 = list(        
      title = "CPU(%)",
      zeroline=TRUE)

  )%>%
  layout(margin=m)


subplot(p5,p6,nrows=1,which_layout = "merge", margin = 0.07,titleX = F, titleY = TRUE)%>%
  layout(margin=ma)
```

I got the following plot:
[image]

But as you can all see in the image,in the graphs of both the plots the y axis 2 is getting hidden.

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without having the dataset to test it exactly, you want to follow msummersgill's advice over at https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/954

The long and short of it:
Under P6's layout, you should specify (instead of yaxis2=):

```
yaxis4 = list(        
      title = "CPU(%)",
      zeroline=TRUE,overlaying="y3")
```